# LibGDX AssetManager: Asset not loaded only on Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, assets

When I try to load a file into the asset manager, LibGDX does not seem to pick it up. However, it works perfect on Windows!
I debugged the finishloading() method and It claims the parameter toLoad = 1 but it does not load.
On windows it would say loaded = 1 in the debugging screen.
Code sample:

```
ParticleEffectLoader.ParticleEffectLoadParameter loadParam = new ParticleEffectLoader.ParticleEffectLoadParameter(particleSystem.getBatches());
ParticleEffectLoader loader = new ParticleEffectLoader(new InternalFileHandleResolver());
Assets.instance.assetManager.setLoader(ParticleEffect.class, loader);
Assets.instance.assetManager.load("bb.pfx", ParticleEffect.class, loadParam);
Assets.instance.assetManager.finishLoading();

effect1=Assets.instance.assetManager.get("bb.pfx",ParticleEffect.class).copy();
```

The last line fails with a AssetNotLoaded on Android. Filenames are case sensitive, so that is not the error.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded: bb.pfx
                                                                      at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.get(AssetManager.java:144)
                                                                      at bvo.games.colorspace.settings.Assets$AssetBillboard.<init>(Assets.java:109)
```

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Don't use `static`s, https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#creating-an-assetmanager

Comment: thanks I will try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Asset class was static, on Android this does give unexpected results, as Xoppa pointed out in his comment. Problem solved. :)